# How to Reset Eclipse RCP perspective programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have made RCP product file in which I have to reset perspective every time. Is there any way by which it will reset perspective before it load ?

Answer (score 2):

If you always want your RCP to start in the same state you can specify the flags

```
-clearPersistedState -persistState false
```

in the Program Arguments section on the Launching tab of the .product file.

`-clearPersistedState` causes Eclipse to drop any persisted state during starting.

`-persistState false` stops Eclipse for persisting the state on exit.

This is for Eclipse 4.x only.

Comment: -clearPersistedState -persistState false works fine but it clears saved perspective too.

Answer (score 1):

`PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().resetPerspective();`

Eclipse 3.x - for Eclipse 4.x, see greg's answer.

Comment: resetPerspective() doesn't always reset perspective.